# Sending Data SMS's in Android on a CDMA phone

Tags: android, sms, cdma

I'm having trouble with the `sendDataMessage()` method in [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html).

Sending a data SMS between 2 GSM emulator's appears to at least partially work, but I get a `NullPointerException` when using the same method on a Verizon CDMA phone.

I found this link to a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7319) for something similar:

> "SmsManager.sendDataMessage() always fails on CDMA devices because there is
>   no code path for it to succeed.  The failure can be seen in the radio log,
>   where com.android.internal.telephony.cdma.sms.BearerData.encodeEmsUserDataPayload()
>   throws a CodingException."

But I'm wondering if anyone's found a workaround to do 
something similar on CDMA phones.

Comment: I think for now I might just settle with sendMessage() and use a special tag in the messages, then intercept all messages and check for the tag, but this is a hack I'd rather not do

Comment: Have you yet resolved this problem? I have the same problem, and I am tending to think that it is a provider (Verizon Wireless in my case) related limitation (or rather restriction).

Comment: Hi @bfly2000, I am coming in on this late, but I am having the same issue. Do you know if this has been resolved to date, and how do you get the radio log?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for GSM and CDMA both

```
String sms = message.getText().toString();

            if(PhoneNumberUtils.isWellFormedSmsAddress(dest))
            {
                for(String contact:multiContact)
                {
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact, null, sms, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(SampleSms.this, "SMS messgae Sent to"+contact, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(SampleSms.this, "SMS messgae Sent failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

I had also used `sendDataMessage()` but I got error. But above code is working fine

Comment: im trying to send a data sms, because I'm using this as a specific method of sending a program data. This isn't going to be a standard text message, and it would get intercepted by an sms messaging client. Even if i set my program to have a high android:priority for the SMS_RECIEVED intent, I still have to deal with parsing and making sure the message is from my program, theres no real way to ensure that I'm not intercepting a real text message.

Comment: Have you used port no in `sendDataMessage()`? However This message is depricated

Comment: of course, i don't think it would work without a port no., and I'm unsure as to why it's deprecated, I was hoping there was a way to mimic a data sms for a cdma network in android at the moment